# 質問に直接答えていない回答はコメントにするべきですか？

Tags: 討議

質問に直接答えるのではなく、前提となる知識、考え方、調査方法といった内容を回答として投稿してはいけないでしょうか？

例えば、 [オブジェクト指向で作成したアプリが起動時にエラーになります。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34528/3054) に対する[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34530/3054) はエラーメッセージを読む方法が無いと思っている回答者に対して、
「その方法はあるので、まずはエラーメッセージを読みましょう」という内容です。
実際のエラーメッセージの読み方も詳しく説明しています。

丁寧な投稿ではありますが、コードの誤りを具体的に指摘し、デバッグを完了させているわけではありません。
このような投稿は回答としては不適切で、コメントにするべきでしょうか。

---

上の回答はレビューでの指摘で既にコメントとして投稿し直されています。
権限の関係で閲覧できない場合を考え、下に全文引用いたします。

> これだけではわからないです。アプリが落ちた時にAndroidStudioにエラーが表示されるはずなので、そちらを確認してみてください。AndroidMonitorというタブを選ぶと出てくるはずです。参考画像では文字が白いですが、赤文字で表示されるのがエラーメッセージです。[image: 参考画像]
>
> 削除者と削除日: 所有者 5月9日 5:16
> 回答日時: 5月8日 0:19 shikajiro
>
> ---
>
> コメント:
> これは質問の答えになりません。建設的な指摘や、作成者にさらなる説明を求めたい場合は、投稿の下にコメントを残してください。 - From Review – nekketsuuu 5月8日 5:10
>
> すいません。書き間違えました。 – shikajiro 5月9日 5:15

---

追記: [再現情報が不足している質問の内容を「エラーの確認方法」を問うものに変更してよいですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/3054) の結果を受け、元質問をロールバックしました。それに伴い、質問を変更しています。回答の削除の取り消しに関しては、この Meta 質問へのご意見により、必要ならば改めて考えたいと思います。

Comment: 質問の意図を変更するような編集を第三者が行うのは適切でしょうか。私はこの編集を取り消し、「原因が知りたい」という元の質問に戻すべきだと思います。

Comment: @suzukis まずはその点を解決すべきかも知れませんね。
[別の Meta 質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/3054)としました。

Comment: @mjy 件の Meta 質問が解決したようですが、こちらの Meta 質問の扱いはどのようにいたしましょうか？ 削除を推薦した一人として、気になっています。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 質問側の編集の是非に関わる論点は排除した Meta 質問に変更させていただきましたので、ご意見募集中です。（例示の削除済み回答は、私が削除の取り消しに一票入れていて、取り消し票はその一票だけという状態です。削除には賛成の方が多そうです）

Answer (score 1):

この件について言えば

> 作成者にさらなる説明を求めたい場合は、投稿の下にコメントを残してください

このレビューコメントにあるとおりで、単なる追加情報の要求にすぎないので回答ではなくコメントの方が適切な投稿です。

本来はコメントにすべき内容であっても、コメントでは説明しきれない(マークアップの制限とか画像がないと説明が難しいとか)場合もありますが、この投稿がそうだとも思えません。たとえば「参考画像では白いですが」を省けば画像がなくても内容は伝わるでしょう。

「質問に直接答えていない回答」と幅を広げてしまうとケースバイケースとなってしまうと思います。直接の回答がしようがない質問というのもままありますので。