# 再現情報が不足している質問の内容を「エラーの確認方法」を問うものに変更してよいですか？

Tags: 討議, 編集

「[オブジェクト指向で作成したアプリが起動時にエラーになります。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34528/3054)」 は当初どこに問題があるのか原因を教えて欲しいという内容でした。
しかし、まずはエラーの確認をするべきであるとして、その確認方法を質問する形に、第三者によって編集が行なわれました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/34528/revisions

このような編集は適切でしょうか？
また、上の質問は編集を取り消し、当初の形に戻すべきでしょうか？

関連: [この回答の削除は、質問の編集により理由が無くなったため、取り消しを提案します](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2479/3054)

---

回答ありがとうございます。
現在寄せられている回答は、第三者の編集としては、やり過ぎだったという点で一致してますね。
ロールバックすべきかに関しては一致していませんが、一票の差があるので、とりあえずロールバックさせていただきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問の趣旨を変更するような第三者による編集は原則不適切な編集としてrevertすべきだと思います。

質問の趣旨を変えるような編集を第三者に許してしまえば、例えば「都合のいいように質問を編集して回答する」ということもできてしまいます。このような編集について程度によって「良い編集」「悪い編集」を判断するのは困難です。

質問者本人による編集だとしても、気づかないまま不適切な回答が追加されるとか、回答を用意していたのに無駄になる、ということもあるのであまりよい行為とは言えないと思います。また、このような事もあるので回答の有無によってこのような編集の可不可を判断できません。

この質問について言えば、質問者はまず調べ方を質問すべきだというのであれば、別に質問するように促せば十分だったと思います。

Answer (score 3):

この元質問については、私が見た時には既に編集後のものになっていました。
Q&A集を目指す stackoverflow としては、編集前のような漠然と「原因を教えて欲しい」といったものより、編集後のような「調べ方を教えて欲しい」の方が利用価値のある情報で、このサイトに合っていると思います。
なので、編集後の質問を最初に見た時には「いい質問をする人がいるもんだ」と感じていました。

しかし、それはそれとして、
この編集では質問の方向性が全く変わってしまっており、たとえ質問者本人が行う場合でも別質問にするような内容になっているし、第三者ならなおさらすべきでなかった、と私は思います。

当初の形に戻すかどうかは、質問者本人が決めれば良いと思います。質問者の考え方として、

- 調べ方を教えてくれれば、今後も役に立つだろうから、その方がいい
- 調べ方より、今のこの状態の原因を知りたい

どちらもありだと思うからです。