# コメントで回答する理由を教えてください

Tags: 討議, コメント, 回答の仕方

ときどき、質問に対する回答相当の内容がコメントされるときがあります。

コメントを打ち込もうとすると「コメントを使って質問に回答しないでください」と表示されるのですが、それでもコメントとして投稿されるということは、回答だと思ってらっしゃらないか、コメントとして投稿したい理由があるのではないかと思っています。もし後者で、その理由がシステム的に解決できるものなのであれば、SE Team にかけあってみる価値があるなと思いました。システム的な対処が難しそうであれば、コミュニティとしてどうすればより良い Q&A を作っていけるか考える機会にしたいです。

そこで、もし一度でも回答っぽいことをコメントとして投稿された覚えのある方がいらっしゃいましたら、どうしてコメントにしたのかを教えていただけませんでしょうか。

関連: [質問に直接答えていない回答はコメントにするべきですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2479/19110)

Comment: コメントのやり取りを続けていく中で **結果として回答となった場合** については他のメタ投稿で議論されているので、今回は(ある程度確信を持っているように見えるにも関わらず)「敢えてコメントで回答を投稿するのはなぜか？」に焦点を絞った方がよいのかなと思います。 / 参考: [コメントで解決済みとなった質問の事後処理](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1812), [コメントで解決した質問には、回答を投稿してほしい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2645)

Comment: コメントとして付けてみます。
まず、単純な理由:ここでの回答はかなり敷居が高く、迂闊に回答すると マイナスされるのが、怖いってのがあります。どうも皆さまの感覚と合わないみたいで、非難されそうだと感じた時。
まあ、最近、そんなでほとんど書かないですが。

Answer (score 6):

時々、コメントを付けたら、それで解決しました、と返されることがあるので該当者の一部と言えそうです。
以前回答を書いていて、以下の様な理由と思われる Down Vote を幾つも貰っていて、それはちょっと嫌だなと思ったので。

- 回答に多数の外部記事へのリンクを書いているため？あるいはリンクが殆どの回答
- 回答が質問内容に合っていないと見なされた？
- 回答内容では解決しなかった？間違っていた？
- 見解の相違とか記述の不足程度と思われるもの？

以下の様な状況で、何か対応/助言する時、コメントを付けることが多いですね。

- 質問内容に関する知識が浅いものしか無いが、調査のヒント/糸口になりそうなことを知っている(または以下のように検索した)
- 質問内容に関する経験が無いが推測は出来そう
- 質問内容では答えるのに十分な情報が不足しているが推測は出来そう
  (ソースコード/データが無かったり、検証のためには不十分な内容だったり)
- 提示されたプログラム/データを修正して動作確認/検証していない(出来る環境に無い)が、解決方法やヒント/糸口を知っている
- 検索して関連しそうな記事を見つけたが、質問内容に当てはまるかどうか判断できなかった
- 検索して該当しそうな記事を見つけたが、短いか長くて複雑(質問内容詳細に対する場合分けの考慮が必要など)で回答とするのに躊躇する
- 意見・観点などを求める質問で、答えてみようと思うもの

Answer (score 6):

「回答」として投稿するには自身が無いけど、質問に含まれるエラーメッセージでweb検索してみたら該当しそうな情報が出てきた時、などでしょうか。

- 自分の守備範囲では無い分野の話題
  スタック・オーバーフローにおいてプログラミング言語としては Python が人気のようですが、私自身はあまり詳しくありません。他の言語の知識も応用して、"もしかしたら該当するかも？" くらいの情報の時にコメントするケースがあります。
- 英語版で類似のケースが見つかった時
  英語もそれほど得意じゃないので、翻訳でうまくニュアンスが伝えられそうにないときは参考リンクだけをコメントするケースがあります。

いずれの場合でも、運よくコメントを踏まえて質問者から「解決した」と返事があった場合には、改めて回答として投稿し直すか、**質問者本人に自己回答を勧める** ようにしています。
スタック・オーバーフローにまだ慣れてないユーザーにサイトの使い方を覚えてもらういい機会なので、一石二鳥だと思っています。

Answer (score 5):

エラーや問題の直接の原因を取り除くことはできるが、それは一般的に回答としては役に立たない、という場合で質問者がそれで満足してしまった場合はコメントが回答になってしまいますね。

[TextFieldのラッパーを作りたいのですが、関数の渡し方が分かりません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62675/textfield%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a9%e3%83%83%e3%83%91%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8c-%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e6%b8%a1%e3%81%97%e6%96%b9%e3%81%8c%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93)

^ 例えばこの質問に対する一般的な回答は、テキストの入力を利用するためには変数にバインドする関数を渡す必要がある、、、みたいなことになるのですが、その前にコンパイルエラーが出ていて段階的に解決しないといけないのですが、とりあえずコンパイルエラーが直ったらOKとなってしまった、というものです。

このようにまず前段のエラーや例外を解決しないと本来の回答を示すことができないが、質問者のレベルが分からないのでまず第一段階として直接の原因を解決するためのアドバイスをコメントしたがそれで終わってしまった、というのはよくあるのではと思います。

Answer (score 4):

私はある程度は「コメントが回答になってしまう」のはしょうがないのかなと思います。
どちらかというと「コメントで回答になってしまった」後の処理を考えるべきかなと思います。
コメントが続いた場合は「チャット」への導線があるように、
（１）ある程度コメントがついた質問には質問者に自己回答への促しをつけるリンクをつける
（２）モデレータさんたちが自己回答への奨励のコメントを気軽に打てるように、「自己回答奨励コメント」テンプレート機能
をつけるとかですかね？

ちなみに
私も割とその傾向が強いようで、直近でもコメントで解決してしまうことが多いようです。
[Laravelのクエリビルダのupdateで元々の値が0に対し0を更新すると0件で返ってくるのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62321/)
[複数のPHPファイルで乱数を共有したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60171/)

私の場合は、おそらく回答はなんとなくわかるけど一旦、環境や質問者の勘違いの確認をコメントでするが、その際コメントに「なぜ」環境や質問者の勘違いを聞いているのかの「理由」を記述してしまうと、自己解決に向かってしまうようです。

それぞれの状況です。
（１）[Laravelのクエリビルダのupdateで元々の値が0に対し0を更新すると0件で返ってくるのはなぜ？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62321/)
質問者がLaravelが原因と考えているが、MySQLを利用している事による影響と推測できたので、MySQLを利用の有無とMySQL仕様を提示しました。

（３）[複数のPHPファイルで乱数を共有したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60171/)
問題を解決するには何らかのストレージを利用する必要があるので、
環境を教えてもらう。ストレージを利用しなきゃいけない理由も記載。

そのまま回答してしまってもいいのですが、コメントで解決したのであれば質問者の自己回答でいいと思っています。
（自己回答の奨励はしていないので、そこは行動カイゼンしたほうがいいですね。。すいません。）

たまに、時間がなくてコメントで理由なく環境だけ聞くこともありますが、なんだか不躾に見えてしまうんですよね。もちろん回答はします。
（例）[Fuel real_ip に HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR の値が入らない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59592/)

環境を聞かず、回答して外れたバージョンもあります。
[Virtualboxの上のUbuntuでCapsLock(Ctrlに入れ替えている)が押し続けられてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57341/)

Answer (score 1):

「どうしてコメントにしたのか」だって？
もちろんノーリスクで評価が欲しいからだよ。

回答に書いたら低評価食らうかもしれないのに、とてもそんなことする気にならないね。
コメントを小出しにしたら律儀にひとつひとつ評価してくれる親切な質問者がいるじゃないか。
彼らは回答が欲しい、僕は評価が欲しい。それならコメントの方がよっぽど効率的でしょ。

もちろん回答を全く書かないわけじゃないけど、低評価がついたらすぐに回答も下げちゃうよ。
あーでもムカつくからとりあえず他の回答に低評価つけてからにしようかな。

質問者の質問をサッと本家SOで検索かけて、それっぽく自分の発案みたいに日本語でコメントすればいいんだから楽なもんだよ。リンクなんかもちろん用意しないよ。あ、でも予防線として「参考までに」とだけ書いとこうかな。僕は僕の評価にしか興味無いし、質問者はそれができなかったからここで質問してるんだしね。

Q&Aとしての健全性？それって僕の評価につながるの？

---

...という人物像を想像したことはあります。

<s>案外コメントのUpvoteを評価に計上しないだけで解決するかもしれません。</s>

---

追記: コメントでコメントによる信用度の変化は無いとご指摘をいただきました。

そうなると単に長文が苦手でコメントの方がアクセスしやすいからでしょうか。
回答を他人が修正できるように、コメントから回答に移動ができればいいのですが。

Comment: 勘違いされている方がいるかも知れないので念のため説明しておくと、コメントに対して反対票ができない一方で、たとえ賛成票を入れても **信用度は変化しません**。 - [コメントに関するヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: 知りませんでした。そうだったんですね。

Answer (score 0):

[Windows10でスクリーンショットを撮った後に切り取り＆スケッチを自動起動するには](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63145/19110)

質問内容の要約：サイトに書かれているようにアプリを自動起動させたい

上の質問で、**個人的には**それをそのまま回答にして良さそうと思ったコメントが複数あり、それらを投稿された方にそのようにした理由を伺ってみました。

> @nekketsuuu さんへ。私の方は推測であり、「自動起動」に対する回答ではなかったのでコメントと致しました。

> nekketsuuuさんへ。自分のコメント内容はwakuwakuさんの「コメント」に対する補足にすぎません。当然ですが回答者の求める解決とも直結しません。

ひとつの事例としてメモしておきたかったので、回答として投稿しておきます。